# TypeError while reading HTML file content in nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to read HTML file content using fs module of nodejs. However, i'm getting TypeError.

can someone please give an idea what's going wrong in my code?

HTML Code.

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>My Header</h1>
    <p>My paragraph</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Nodejs Code

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  //Open a file on the server and return it's content:
  fs.readFile('demofile1.html', function(err, data) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write("Hey");
    res.write(data);
    return res.end();
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

Error

> _http_outgoing.js:457
>       throw new TypeError('First argument must be a string or Buffer');
>       ^
>
> TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer
>       at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.write (_http_outgoing.js:457:11)
>       at ReadFileContext.callback (D:\Java\Nodejs\public\readfile.js:8:9)
>       at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:366:13)

Comment: How about doing some basic debugging? `console.log(typeof data); console.log(data); console.log(err);`

Comment: Thanks Quentin..!1 for helping me with these basic debugging commands. It helped me to identify an error of file path.